# How to pass URL strings to my server-side click handler in a jQuery $.each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-linking

I have url values in my client-side script. While looping over them, I want to create links that will pass these URL values on-click back to my server-side click handler. The server-side code (**`/logclick`**) records the time and destination of the click for audit purposes before the user is directed to the url location that was passed as a parameter to the `/logclick` server-side handler.

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, item) 
{
        $('#link').append("<a href='" + item.url + "'></a>");
});
```

The question is how to write the link so that the "virtual link" passes the destination URL to the server-side code without misinterpreting the destination URL as part of the "virtual link"?

What I mean is, if the "virtual link" looks like this:

```
/logclick/http://www.google.com/reader/view/subscription/a
```

then the server-side code will complain that it doesn't recognize this destination (it will think the google.com destination is part of the **`/logclick`** url-route instead of a string value that is being passed to the **`/logclick`** route.

But, in the context of a jQuery `$.each` loop, how would I create URLs that `POST` values to the **`/logclick`** handler rather than `GET`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your server-side framework is doing, but you may need to encode that part of the URL.

```
$('#link').append("<a href='" + encodeURIComponent(item.url) + "'></a>");
```

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

> But, in the context of a jQuery $.each loop, how would I create URLs that POST values to the /logclick handler rather than GET?

In order to send a POST request you need to use existing FORM element for that.

```
<form id="my-post-form" method="post" action="/uri-router/">
<input type="hidden" name="item-url" value="" /></form>

...

$.each(data.items, function(i, item)
{
     var link = $("<a />");
     link.attr('href', item.url).click(function(){
        $('#my-post-form input[name=item-url]').val($(this).attr('href'));
        $('#my-post-form')[0].submit();
        return false; 
     });
     $('#link').append(link);
});
```

Comment: Can't you use a jquery `$.post` without a form?

Comment: $.post is simplier, yeah. Depends on what you want and what you need ;)